# arbitrary order of nodequeues in a view

Tags: views, nodes

What is the best way to arbitrary order nodequeues in a view?

- Drupal 6.26
- Nodequeue 2.11
- Views 2.16

Comment: You can select sort order as Global:random in view sort settings ..

Comment: arbitrary != random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up using subqueues, was not quite what I wanted.